# unable to load pypy library: libpypy-c.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: fedora, yum, libraries

I'm usign fedora and yum package manager, when I was tired to config uwsgi with pypy this error occured:

```
unable to load pypy library: libpypy-c.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I was looking for `libpypy-c.so` path to set in config. witch package provide it?

```
yum provides libpypy-c.so
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: www.mirrorservice.org
No matches found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First link on google: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/libpypy-c.so

With

```
dnf install pypy-libs
```

you should be good, if you use some up-to-date verison of Fedora (these days 22 or 23).

Comment: Hi, i thinks that not about it. my yum result is `Package pypy-libs-2.4.0-1.fc21.x86_64 already installed and latest version`.

Comment: Fedora 21 is EOL and as you can see on the above link, there are no more packages for `fc21`. You should update to current version to these updates and other, more important security updates (then it will be `update` instead of `install`).